# Mocking configuration objects with MockFactory

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

I am doing some tests, and in many cases I have a configuration of an FTP / HTTP.

I am working with Scala and the following libraries in my sbt:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % Test,
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock" % "4.1.0" % Test,
```

I am doing for the following code as an example of a configuration mocked, inside of my test:

```
val someConfig = SomeConfig(
  endpoint = "", 
  user = "", 
  password = "", 
  companyName="", 
  proxy = ProxyConfig("", 2323)
)
```

But I feel it is not nice to do this for each configuration that I am going to be dealing with...

I would like to create the following:

```
val someConfig = mock[SomeConfig]
```

but when my code tries to reach the proxy property, which is a case class, it fails with a null pointer exception.

I would like to know how to mock case classes that contains other case classes and make my code a bit more clear, is there a way to do this with MockFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to mock it like this:

```
val someConfig = mock[SomeConfig]
when(someConfig.proxy).thenReturn(ProxyConfig("", 2323))
```

So it will return `ProxyConfig("", 2323)` when you try to get `someConfig.proxy`.

The above code is using Mockito due to a [known limitation of ScalaMock](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/40#issuecomment-284016815)

Comment: would you provide your configuration of sbt / or any other to know which packages should I have for that syntax?, also which extentions you use in the particular test case would be great. I only see this working for getters of a certain private property, but not for public properties of a case class nested with another case class... may be something like scala faker could be a solution, but I expected this to be solved by mock factory....

Comment: The above syntax is from Mockito.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of case classes are translated into `val` fields, and ScalaMock has a [known limitation](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/40#issuecomment-284016815) where it is not able to mock `val`, so I think it is not possible to directly do this with ScalaMock.

Mockito does have this capability.